# How do I resize form programmatically using C#?

Tags: c#, forms, resize

This seems simple enough, and I have followed advice I have found on other posts here. If my picturebox grows to accommodate a large image, I want the form to grow a little more, so there's some whitespace under the photo (otherwise, it looks like the form cropped the photo).

```
        if ((pictureBox1.Height + 25) >= this.Height)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(this.Width, (pictureBox1.Height + 35));
            this.Refresh(); // tried with and without refresh 
        }
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. When going step by step, I see that the Height of the form never changes. I've read here on stack overflow that setting minimum size or maximum size can cause this behaviour, but both are set to their defaults (0,0).

Suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Using the Size and Height properties doesn't make much sense, it includes the window's titlebar and the borders.  Use ClientSize instead.  And pictureBox1.Bottom.  And make sure you didn't set the MaximumSize property.

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to work for me.  I would try putting a break in your code at the refresh and examining the values that you are getting and then stepping through the refresh and checking again.  Check to make sure that you are getting the expected values for this.Height and pictureBox1.Height.

Here is the exact code that I used to test this:

```
this.Size = new Size(300, 300);
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
pictureBox1.Size= new Size(700, 700);
this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
if ((pictureBox1.Height + 25) >= this.Height)
{
    this.Size = new Size(this.Width, (pictureBox1.Height + 35));
    this.Refresh(); // tried with and without refresh 
}
```

Your going to have to post more of the code in order to get much help.